# non breaking white space between text and <a>

Tags: css

How do i provide a non breaking white space between a text element and `<a>` tag all nested within a `span`

```
<span>
    <label> this is xyz</label>
    <a href =""> 
</span>
```

I want to do this using CSS and not with `&nbsp`;

Also I have tried using all combinations of `white-space`, but it wasn't any good.

Comment: Provide some relevant HTML/CSS please.

Comment: Provide valid, meaningful HTML, please.

Comment: OP provided code from the start, but the markup made it hidden. No need to close on that account.

Comment: The markup is not valid or meaningful, and “a non breaking white space” is does not make much sense either.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela OP evidently made an effort, providing code and options explored. Invalid markup does not constitute "invalid code to reproduce the problem". It might very will be the *problem* that you should point out in the comments or answers.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a margin for the tag, and set `white-space:nowrap` to prevent breaking, if white-space property isnt working then there might be other styles that might be interfering with it, or even other html elements, as your current code in the question is not complete we cannot see what the full markup looks like and tell.

for instance if some style is setting your anchor tags to be block element (`display:block;`), this would cause it to break to new line even with `white-space` property. Try adding in `display:inline` to the style as well to see if it helps

html

```
<span>
    <label> this is xyz</label>
    <a href ="">some text</a>
</span>
```

css

```
span {
   white-space:nowrap;
}
span a {
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
  display:inline;
}
```

<kbd>**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzmzU/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: This does not make the spaces between the elements non-breaking.

Comment: added `white-space:nowrap` to correct

Answer (score 1):

Please use follwing CSS and HTML:--

HTML:-

```
<span>xyz<a href="http:ggogle.com">LINK</a></span>
```

CSS:-

```
a:before
{
 content:" ";
}
a{text-decoration:none;}
```

See the fiddle:--
http://jsfiddle.net/npsingh/TJhh7/2/show

Comment: remove the period from before `a`, that makes it look for a class name `a`

Comment: thanks patrick, just mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS, see the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property:

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">
    <label>this is xyz</label>
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
</span>
```

Comment: _"Also I have tried using all combinations of white-space : but not were of any good."_

Comment: @j08691 I saw that note, but regardless of that, I think this is the correct solution. The fact that the OP mentioned that he tried it and it didn't work, doesn't actually mean it's not working. He might have tried it on the wrong elements.